# AngularJS: Required form field not woking with ng-click submit

Tags: angularjs, forms, button, ng-submit

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
     <form ng-submit="submit() ">
       <textarea ng-model="text" required></textarea>

       <div  ng-click="submit()" style="background-color:#ff00ff;cursor:pointer;width:100px;">Create !</div>

       <button type="submit" style="background-color:#ff00ff;cursor:pointer;width:100px;">Create !</button>

    </form>
    {{list}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to submit an Angular form with a custom ***div*** button but when I do it like above, the "required" statements are not taken into account like it is done for the ***button***.

When the textarea is empty the first button runs the submit() function anyway.
Is it possible to have the same behavior as the ***button*** ?

Here is a JsFiddle illustrating this:
http://jsfiddle.net/xKkvj/55/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should be using an `input` rather than a `div`, eg:

```
<input type="submit" ng-click="submit()" style="background-color:#ff00ff;cursor:pointer;width:100px;">Create !</input>
```

I've tested it on your jsFiddle, and it works fine.

If you really must use a `<div>`, use it to wrap the `<input>`

**UPDATE**

It looks like you can't use anything other than an `input` or a `button` as that is what `ngForm` listens to for form submission. You could either extend `ngForm` or you could use a hidden button and trigger that from your div like so:

```
<div onClick="document.getElementById('hiddenButton').click();" style="background-color:#0000ff;cursor:pointer;width:100px;">Create !</div>
<button id='hiddenButton' type="submit" style="display:none;">Create !</button>
```

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rapsac/bty6vbqy/). Hopefully this'll do the trick for you.

Comment: the input with type="submit" behaves like a button. Wrapping it in a div just creates a button in the div. My goal is to use the div as a button

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit form from a `div` element, then you should manually test if form is valid in your `submit` handler:

```
function sumbit() {
if (form.$invalid) {
return;
}
// Other code...
}
```

The point is that when you submit your form via `<input type="submit"/>`, then form validation check is performed internally & form handler do not invoked in case of invalid form.

**UPDATE**

Your jsfiddle form handler should look like:

```
$scope.submit = function () {
        if ($scope.submitCreateSurveyForm.$invalid) {
            return;
        }
        if ($scope.text) {
            $scope.list.push($scope.text);
            $scope.text = '';
        }
        console.log("sent");
    };
```